# Stripe API - Search Based on Metadata

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I have an application that uses a deep integration with Stripe.  My platform is occasionally charging the connected accounts and I am storing information about these charges in the metadata of the charge itself.

I want to display this information back to the connected account so I am using the Charge Service to list charges.  However I want to filter that list based on some metadata key/value pair so that I don't have to list all of the charges each time, for every connected account.

Is there a clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Stripe recently added [Search API](https://stripe.com/docs/search-api) that allows search by metadata. Currently, it does not have .NET / C# integration but you can query using HTTP call directly:

Example from [their docs](https://stripe.com/docs/search-api#examples):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/search/charges \
  -u sk_test_daHanKyJOCiXCeBsa65biLML00wylimZ8S: \
  --data-urlencode "query=metadata['key']:'value'" \
  -H "Stripe-Version: 2020-08-27;search_api_beta=v1" \
  -G
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering based on metadata is not supported.

Since you are doing this across Connected accounts, a better approach would be to store the Charge ID and metadata on your end so that you don't have to list and paginate through charges, looking for particular metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the "TransferGroup" property of the ChargeCreateOptions object.  I basically set the TransferGroup property to a unique value for each connected account which I can then query later.

**CREATE THE CHARGE**

```
//THERE IS NO ID IN THE REQUEST OPTIONS BECAUSE
//WE ARE USING THE PLATFORM
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
{
  ApiKey = {API Key}
};

//CHARGE OPTIONS
var chargeOptions = new ChargeCreateOptions
{
  Amount = {AMOUNT},
  Currency = "usd",
  Description = $"Platform Charge",
  SourceId = {StripeId},
  Metadata = {MetaData},
  TransferGroup = {Unique String For Each Connected Account}
};

//CREAT AND RETURN THE CHARGE
var chargeService = new ChargeService();
return chargeService.Create(chargeOptions, requestOptions);
```

**QUERY THE PLATFORM CHARGES BASED ON TRANSFER GROUP**

```
    public List<Charge> StripePlatformCharges(string apiKey, int days, string transferGroup)
    {
        try
        {
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
            {
                ApiKey = apiKey
            };

            ChargeListOptions chargeListOptions = new ChargeListOptions()
            {
                CreatedRange = new DateRangeOptions()
                {
                    GreaterThanOrEqual = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days)
                },
                TransferGroup = transferGroup
            };

            ChargeService chargeService = new ChargeService();
            return chargeService.List(chargeListOptions, requestOptions).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error getting stripe charges from the platform", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe recently released a Search API which offers filtering by metadata for certain resources including charges. The documentation is at https://stripe.com/docs/search

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Look up charges matching a custom metadata value.

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_51LGPbLI0iFqL5wBv4TG3Szk5tH8O5pJW5CoFG6kZd28mTjypF62yu7oSKtYbq94XWP2jMYgiWOzYocIA3P5zJjpW00yezd1x34";

var options = new ChargeSearchOptions { Query = "metadata['key']:'value'" };
var service = new ChargeService();
service.Search(options);
```

Link for more [information](https://stripe.com/docs/search)